# Tree heap Haskell code

Tags: haskell, tree, heap

I'd like a review of Haskell tree heap code in [Turning a tree into a heap in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639793/turning-a-tree-into-a-heap-in-haskell/16655447#comment24033886_16655447).

```
module Heapify where

data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) 
   deriving Show

ourTree = Node (Node (Leaf 8) 2 (Leaf 4))  3  (Node (Leaf 1) 7 (Leaf 9))

atTop :: Tree a -> a
atTop (Leaf a) = a
atTop (Node _ a _) = a

replaceTop :: Ord a => Tree a -> a -> Tree a
replaceTop (Leaf _) a = Leaf a
replaceTop (Node l _ r) a = heapify (Node l a r)

adjustLeft :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a
adjustLeft (Leaf a) = Leaf a   -- But we shouldn't ask to do this. 
adjustLeft  node@(Node l a r) 
     | topL <= a = node
     | otherwise = Node (replaceTop l a) topL r
         where topL = atTop l

adjustRight :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a
adjustRight (Leaf a) = Leaf a   -- But we shouldn't ask to do this. 
adjustRight  node@(Node l a r) 
     | topR <= a = node
     | otherwise = Node l topR (replaceTop r a) 
         where topR = atTop r

doTop :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a
doTop (Leaf a) = Leaf a
doTop node@(Node l a r) 
    | atTop l > atTop r = adjustLeft node
    | otherwise         = adjustRight node

heapify :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a
heapify (Leaf a) = Leaf a
heapify (Node l a r) = doTop (Node (heapify l) a (heapify r))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Correctness? Unanticipated cases?

```
module Heapify where

data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) 
   deriving Show
```

I think this **can't host an even number of elements**. `fromList [1,2]` seems impossible.

```
ourTree = Node (Node (Leaf 8) 2 (Leaf 4))  3  (Node (Leaf 1) 7 (Leaf 9))
```

an example data.

```
atTop :: Tree a -> a
atTop (Leaf a) = a
atTop (Node _ a _) = a
```

ok.

```
replaceTop :: Ord a => Tree a -> a -> Tree a
replaceTop (Leaf _) a = Leaf a
replaceTop (Node l _ r) a = heapify (Node l a r)
```

**produces a heap**. doesn't know what data was put on top, must re-heapify. *Does not use the knowledge* whether `l`/`r` are in fact heaps already or not. If was called on a heap,  both must have been heaps already. The usual flow would be for `heapify` to be called on arbitrary trees, but `replaceAtTop` to be called on heaps only. *This* might have an impact on performance.

```
adjustLeft :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a
adjustLeft (Leaf a) = Leaf a   -- But we shouldn't ask to do this. 
adjustLeft  node@(Node l a r) 
     | topL <= a = node
     | otherwise = Node (replaceTop l a) topL r
         where topL = atTop l
```

**assumes `l` was already a heap**. If not, `l` might harbor some number yet bigger than `topL` and the `otherwise` clause could produce a non-heap (`replaceTop` fully heapifies its argument so its biggest number will get floated to its top).

```
adjustRight :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a
adjustRight (Leaf a) = Leaf a   -- But we shouldn't ask to do this. 
adjustRight  node@(Node l a r) 
     | topR <= a = node
     | otherwise = Node l topR (replaceTop r a) 
         where topR = atTop r
```

similarly to the above, **assumes `r` was a heap**. Both functions assume both `l` and `r` were heaps actually, because `r` (corr., `l`) is kept unchanged. So **both assume that only the top element can be out of place** before the call, and produce a heap under that assumption. If the assumption does not hold, the produced value will not be a heap.

```
doTop :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a
doTop (Leaf a) = Leaf a
doTop node@(Node l a r) 
    | atTop l > atTop r = adjustLeft node
    | otherwise         = adjustRight node
```

assuming both `l` and `r` were heaps before call, produce a heap.

```
heapify :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a
heapify (Leaf a) = Leaf a
heapify (Node l a r) = doTop (Node (heapify l) a (heapify r))
```

assuming `heapify` fulfills its promise, OK. Base case (`Leaf a`): OK.

So, **OK** (except for the data definition deficiency).

### Call graph

```
 heapify                             (does not assume l/r were heaps)
    |
    |_____  heapify
    |
    |_____  doTop
            |
            |____ adjustLeft / adjustRight    (assume l/r were heaps)
                  |
                  |____ replaceTop   (does not assume l/r were heaps)
                        |
                        |_____ heapify
```

### Performance?

So, heapify essentially is

```
heapify (Leaf a) = Leaf a
heapify (Node l a r) 
   | a >= top    = Node lh a rh
   | ltop > rtop = Node (replaceTop lh a) ltop rh                 -- lh is a heap!
   | otherwise   = Node lh                rtop (replaceTop rh a)  -- rh is a heap!
  where
    lh   = heapify l    ----- superfluous, == id when called from (1)    -- (2)
    rh   = heapify r    ----- superfluous, == id when called from (1)    -- (2)
    ltop = atTop lh
    rtop = atTop rh
    top  = max ltop rtop
    replaceTop (Leaf _)     a = Leaf a
    replaceTop (Node l _ r) a = heapify (Node l a r)   ------- (1)
```

Looks a very heavy recursion.

---

One way to fix this is to assume that `heapify` will be called only on heaps, not on arbitrary trees. Then the fix is simply to eliminate the two (2) calls. Then it  becomes logarithmic.

- Heaps would need to be created from lists. The usual way is `fold`/`insertElem`.
- The `data` type definition needs to be adjusted to allow insertion of *one* element into a heap tree. The definitions will have to be readjusted. Probably easier done with small snippets, like in OP code. `atTop` would have to produce a `Maybe` value, as now empty heaps become a possibility (say, one of the children of a `fromList [1,2]` heap tree - now both subtrees are *heaps*, and one is empty).
- The whole balance/depth issue is untouched here.

It's probably simpler to re-write `replaceTop` to essentially duplicate the above code, without the calls to `heapify`. It will now assume it's operating on heaps only, not on arbitrary trees. This will make `replaceTop` logarithmic. Leaves all the other problems unaddressed.

```
replaceTop (Leaf _)       a = Leaf a      -- operates on heaps!
replaceTop (Node lh _ rh) a               -- lh, rh are heaps!
   | a >= top       = Node lh a rh
   | ltop > rtop    = Node (replaceTop lh a) ltop rh               
   | otherwise      = Node lh                rtop (replaceTop rh a)
  where
    ltop = atTop lh
    rtop = atTop rh
    top  = max ltop rtop
```

According to [master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#See_also) for `2T(n/2) + O(log(n))` case, `heapify` will be `O(n)` then, assuming a balanced tree. A balanced tree can be built from a list in `O(n)` time.

`removeTop` will most probably be `O(log(n))`.

Comment: (I read that it was faster to heapify an unsorted balanced tree than to repeatedly insert.)

Comment: yes. your approach pays off. :)

Comment: http://cs.brynmawr.edu/Courses/cs206/spring2012/slides/10_PriorityQueues.pdf has the algorithms in question and discusses the complexities; explains O(n) for heapification of unsorted array/tree.

Comment: It does, using O(1) array lookup. Why not post an answer along those lines to the original question, using mutible arrays?

Comment: @AndrewC too much work. :)